memorization in the browser of a text input field in a form?
I have this little form
<form id="_F">
<input id="_A" name="_A" required type="text" autocomplete="on" autofocus/>
<input id="_B" required type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
<input id="_C" type="submit" value="Calc"/>
<input id="_R" type="text" readonly="true"/>
</form>
<script>
// form processing
_F.addEventListener("submit", calc);
function calc(event) {
    // do not send data
    event.preventDefault();
    // perform calculation
    _R.value = _A.value + _B.value;
    _A.focus();
}
</script>

to which is associated the calc function which interrupts the submission, performs and displays the calculation in the _R field from the _A and _B fields.
I want my browser to remember the _A field, so I've added the attributes name, required and autocomplete.
this works with firefox and edge, which list previously entered values, but not with chromium, which turns a deaf ear.
is there anything missing from this form for it to work with chromium ?
Note that I haven't tried this with chrome.

I've just tried it with the latest version of chrome and it memorizes the _A field as required : on the PC, the problem is therefore specific to chromium.
I specify on PC because on Android, firefox doesn't save the field like its cousin on PC.
adding the autocomplete attribute (on or _A) to the form tag doesn't change the problem.

I think you're relying on a feature that doesn't function exactly the same across browsers and platforms. Perhaps sometimes an actual form submission is needed before something is remembered. And there can also be user preferences that can change this. You can play a more active role in remembering it by adding a bit of Javascript and storing the value in localStorage.

@KIKOSoftware  yes, that must be it, one is not the other : I hope it is not the same with localStorage on which I'm going to work...
